# msbuild netcoreapp2 referencing .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: msbuild, .net-core-2.0

My VS2017 upd3 solution includes a .Net core 2.0 project which is referncing another project (classlibrary targeting .net framework 4.6.1) within the same solution.

If i do a build on my local machine the solution get compiled successful.

But the msbuild task on TFS2017 upd2 fails with the following error:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets(87,5): Error : The project "D:\AgentWork\1\s\..\..\..\xyz.csproj" targets ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0". Referencing ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" is not possible.
```

FYI - Translated the error from german to english.

Build Server got "NET CORE 2.0 SDK" and latest "Build Tools" by using "Visual Studio Installer" installed.

[Local install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akBLp.png)

[Build Server install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kANPG.png)

There is no option to install ".net framework 4.6.1 developer tools" for core applications at visual studio build tools installer.

Any suggestions what to do so that the build will succeed.

Core Project File...

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\someproject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>    

</Project>
```

Packages.config of someproject.csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="RabbitMQ.Client" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net451" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Is your local installation up to date? (latest vs version, .net core 2.0.0 sdk installed in addition to VS) - you should get the same error in VS

Comment: Yes it is, but before i did the VS update to Version 15.3.5 and installing net core sdk 2.0.0 i got many issues.

Now local everything seems to be fine.

Why you think i should get same errors local?

Comment: Once the net* project uses the package reference style of using NuGet packages, the error will occur (because it is not a supported scenario). you'd need to share the projects (and possibly packages.config) to figure out what went wrong. how do you restore nuget packages?

Comment: nuget restore task (using current nuget.exe 4.3.0)

Comment: @MartinUllrich: shared the project.csproj and the packages.config file

Comment: @Harry I just created a .Net core 2.0 project which is referencing another project (classlibrary targeting .net framework 4.6.1) within the same solution as you mentioned, every thing works correctly. Could you please share the detail steps to reproduce the issue, especially the steps which build in TFS? Please provide demo project if possible.